# How to get ng-repeat to work with orderby

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to sort dropdown options based on a setting called 'IsDefault' DESC and then name, however it seems adding the orderBy per the different examples I've looked at doesn't seem to work.

Data is pulled from the database via nHibernate by running a 'select' query.

The call to get the data is made from the controller via this code:

```
 $scope.getPlaylists = function(activityId){
    PlaylistModalService.getPlaylistsForActivity(activityId)
    .then(function (data) {
        if(data){
            $scope.playlistDataForActivity = data.Results;
            $scope.numPlaylistOwned = data.MaxCount;
        } else {
            $scope.playlistDataForActivity = [];
            $scope.numPlaylistOwned = 0;
        }
        $scope.isDataAvailable = true;            
        MaintainFocusinModal("addToPlaylistModalTplModal");
        SetFocusToFirstUserControl("addToPlaylistModalTplModal");
        CloseModalOnEscClick("addToPlaylistModalTplModal");
    });
};
```

The .cshtml file that contains the dropdown has the following code

```
<select id="playListOpt" class="form-control"
        ng-model="playlistItem.selectedObjectId"
        ng-change="resetModal()" ng-required="true">
    <option role="option" value="0" selected>
      @Resources.L_LMS_ActDetails.CreateNewPlaylist
    </option>
    <option role="option"
            ng-repeat="playlistItem in playlistDataForActivity 
                       | orderBy:playlistItem.IsDefault:reverse track by playlistItem.Id" 
            value="{{playlistItem.Id}}">                                        
      {{playlistItem.Name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

I have tried the following:

```
ng-repeat="playlistItem in playlistDataForActivity | orderBy:playlistItem.IsDefault:reverse track by playlistItem.Id"
ng-repeat="playlistItem in playlistDataForActivity | orderBy:playlistItem.IsDefault"
```

Is there a way to get the orderBy to work within the ng-repeat? Thank you!

Comment: Is `IsDefault` part of each `playlistItem`? If Yes, then your orderBy should be like this  `ng-repeat="playlistItem in playlistDataForActivity | orderBy:'IsDefault'"`

Comment: That worked! Thank you.